# SharePoint 2013 workflow different approvers for documents

Tags: workflow, document-library, document, approval-process, item

Can I create a publishing approval workflow, applying different approvers and publishers for each document of the same library

Answer (score 0):

If each document will have a fixed Approver, maybe this might work: Create a column to have the Approver value. Then in SharePoint Designer, you can check this column with if statements to pick the different approver.